# Is there an equivalent of Ctrl + Shift + L from Eclipse in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

Is there an equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (show shortcut references) from Eclipse in IntelliJ IDEA?

I am switching to it from Eclipse but I have to check the keymaps frequently and I would like to have access to the quick reference of shortcuts instead of opening the settings to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Learning shortcuts**: I switched from Eclipse, too. Initially I started with the Eclipse key bindings, but then decided to switch completely. I used [KeyPromoter](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=1003) for about 2 days, it is annoying but increases the learning curve heavily. `Help->Find Action...` (Ctrl+Shift+A) helps, too.

**Reference card**: After that I printed my own shortcut reference. Took one hour, but it was worth the time, because I have adapted some shortcuts and some shortcuts are displayed incorrectly in IntelliJ Idea. [Here's a Word template](http://victorvolle.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/intellij-german-keyboard-shortcuts-reference/).

Answer (score 0):

Command + Shift + A displays a field that performs a search on an action or option name. Shortcuts along with their corresponding keymap are displayed during the search.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use "Shift Shift" that it searc everywhere shorcuts included.
So for example if I need to search "Optimize import" I do
Shift Shift and write "import" or "optimize" and it appear.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ctrl + Shift + L (show shortcut references) from Eclipse must do "Introduce variable..." In Idea it is Alt + Shift + V  or with menu Refactor/Introduce variable...
May be useful to somebody(begginers like me :) ).

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is Ctrl+Shift+F to search text everywhere in the project.